# Is it possible to bypass linux bridge device and assign linux vlan directly to bridge member on proxmox (Debian)?

Tags: linux-networking, vlan, bridge, proxmox

I came up with the following situation. We have a Proxmox node with a 40gb Mellanox QSFP+ card connected to switch. The 40gb interface is added as a slave to vlan aware linux bridge. To that bridge there are two linux vlans created: one for proxmox management and one for storage. Below is the screenshot from the configuration page.

[image: Proxmox network configuration]

The linux vlans are configured such that the linux bridge is used as a raw device for the storage and management vlan.

Is it possible to "bypass" the linux bridge and tap the storage and management vlan directly to the 40gb interface in order to avoid cpu overhead for the software bridge and still maintain the linux bridge for vm connections? We would like to avoid adding another fiber connection for the storage network.

Comment: I think the easiest way to archive this is to ask on proxmox forum and let us know what is the answer

Comment: @djdomi Proxmox is basically just a debian + quemu combo. Networking is standard linux stuff there. From the Proxmox wiki: Proxmox VE is using the Linux network stack. The configuration can be done either via the GUI, or by manually editing the file /etc/network/interfaces, which contains the whole network configuration

Comment: I am aware about the facts due i use proxmox since Version 4,but most it is a more active community

Comment: It's not clear on which device(s) the vlans are tagged, but I guess they are on the bridge? If so you might need to tag the vlans directly on the physical nics then bridge the vlans instead.... Could you share the `/etc/network/interface` file and output from `ip addr show`.

Comment: Could you also a bit better explain what it is you are trying to accomplish. E.g. is the storage on the proxmoxbox and to be accessed directly from outside the proxmox box via the switch, or is the storage used by the proxmox-box the other side of the switch and the proxmox-box is to access it without having to bridge the connection?
(If the later it might be as simple as putting the Storage vlan directly on the ifc instead of on the bridge.)